# Upload a string as a text file to a server, js (node accepted too, I guess)

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, file, firebase-storage

So, I have a firebase storage server, and I wish to store the path to every uploaded file inside a text file, for future reference. So, every time I upload a file, I will read my paths text file from the server, then add the latest path/string to it, then re-upload it. The only thing being is that I don't think we can upload a String to firebase just like that. How do I convert the modified string back into a file? Upon that, I do not know how to read data from the downloaded text file to, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, there's a section [of the documentation titled "Upload files from a string"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string), then there's ["Download data via URL"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).

Comment: The rest seems fine, but I cannot get that downloaded url as a String, to modify. It can either be downloaded to the system, or rendered internally (like if it is an image), but not extracted as a string.

Comment: I'll mark your solution as the answer, if only you could find a way to get that uploaded string back, AS a string, manipulate it as a string, then upload it back to the cloud.